# Error on trying to use Dataframe.to_json method

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to export a pandas dataframe to JSON with no luck. I've tried:

all_data.to_json("spdata.json") and all_data.to_json()

I get the same attribute error on both: **'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_json'**. Just to make sure something isn't wrong with the DataFrame, i tested writing it to_csv and that worked.

Is there something i'm missing in my syntax or package i need to import? I am running Python version 2.7.5 which is part of an Enthought Canopy Express package. Imports at the beginning of my code are:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
```

Comment: you need at least pandas 0.12

Comment: Rookie mistake. I installed my python environment about 3 weeks after the pandas 0.12 release so assumed i was up to date. Just updated pandas and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method was [introduced to 0.12](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#i-o-enhancements), so you'll need to [upgrade your pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) to be able to use it.